# I want to compare values of some cells in vba but Code gives me run time error if N/A is found so suggest me the code that compares values with "#N/A"

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

The below code is working fine if my cell value is not `#N/A` but I want to compare my values with `#N/A` as well so could you please help me with changes in the code given below:

```
enter code here
Lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Lastrow

If Cells(i, "AO").Value = "X" And Cells(i, "AP").Value = "X" Then
Cells(i, "N").Value = Cells(i, "M").Value * (-1)
Cells(i, "AA").Value = Cells(i, "M").Value
Cells(i, "AX").Value = "some content"
End If
Next i
```

Comment: n/a or N/A is a common abbreviation in tables and lists for the phrase not applicable, not available, or no answer. So you can't compare with nothing. You could add an exception to your code with an If Statement if you expect the `#N/A` value to be nothing.

Comment: Are these #N/A `constants` or `formulae` ?

Comment: These are the result of lookup formula

Answer (score 2):

This is how to see, whether two cells are equal to `#NA`. Build the logic in your checks:

```
Public Sub TestMe()        
    If (Range("A1") = CVErr(xlErrNA)) And (Range("B1") = CVErr(xlErrNA)) Then
        'some logic
    End If        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much but this can only be applied in the cases when I want to check against "#N/A" values but what if I want to check like If Cells(i, "AO").Value = "X" And Cells(i, "AP").Value = "X" Then means I want that if my particular cells are having X then do something, in that case, code checks those cells which are having "#N/A" and can't compare it with X or any other value so kindly suggest how I apply CVErr(xlErrNA) in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider adding another "IF..End If" to verify if a cell where you are testing conditions contains an error value.

Example code will be like below:

```
    Sub HandleErrorCells()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To Lastrow
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(Cells(i, "AO").Value) Or Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(Cells(i, "AP").Value) Then
            Cells(i, "AX").Value = "Column AO or AP has error cell"
        Else
            If Cells(i, "AO").Value = "X" And Cells(i, "AP").Value = "X" Then
                If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "M").Value) Then
                    Cells(i, "N").Value = Cells(i, "M").Value * (-1)
                    Cells(i, "AA").Value = Cells(i, "M").Value
                    Cells(i, "AX").Value = "some content"
                Else
                    Cells(i, "AX").Value = "Column M has non numeric data"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but what I want is any cell which is having "#N/A" value is being compared with any text, value or number without run time error.

Comment: So do you mean there are error values in columns M as well? Your code is making references to columns M, N, AA, AO, AP & AX out of which error cell will matter only for column AO, AP & M only as those are being used for checking. Rest are being populated based on inputs.

Comment: @yashikavaish I have revised code to check column M content. I have used Isnumeric in place of Iserror since the formula implementation needs the data in column to be numeric.